# Extracting ancillary date from array in R

Tags: r, arrays

I have an object called `data` (representing a field of wind strengths at geographical locations) obtained by using some code to read in a .grib file:

```
> data
ecmf : u-component of wind  
Time:
2020/07/09 z00:00 0-0 h 
Domain summary:
601 x 351 domain
Projection summary:
proj= latlong 
NE = ( 50 , 75 )
SW = ( -10 , 40 )
Data summary:
-89.06099 -50.08242 -41.13694 -43.42623 -34.77617 -25.03278
```

`data` is `601 x 351` array of doubles:

```
> typeof(data)
[1] "double"
> is.array(data)
[1] TRUE
> dim(data)
[1] 601 351
```

but, as shown above, it also has extra information attached beyond the numerical values of the array elements (`Time:`, `Projection summary` etc). How do I extract these? Attempts such as `data$time` do not seem to work.

Comment: Check what `str(data)` returns as that will usually give more information about the object

Comment: In the `str` output, you may find *names* (start with `$`) and *slots* (start with a `@`, common with `sp` and geospatial objects, among many). If you post the output of `str(data)`, we will have a much better chance at suggesting ways to extract the date from that.

Comment: Try `attributes(data)`. If you're dealing with a S4 data (most likely for a GRIB file), you can also use `attributes(data@var)` for any specific slot. But as pointed in the other commentaries, it's hard to tell without knowing the structure of your object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments to the question, I was able to access the values I wanted using `attributes()`. `attributes(data)` returns a list of all the relevant elements.